# Driver detected a controller error on disk that doens't exist

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, freeze

Since a week or so, sometimes when I boot Windows 8 my computers immediately locks up. I can still move the mouse cursor without problems and access some GUI elements without any delay whatsoever, but I can't open any new programs or windows. Sound like a storage problem, right? This won't solve itself btw. I have to hard reset (since the PC isn't responding)

Windows Event Viewer shows multiple occurrences one of the following variants:

The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk3\DR3

The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk4\DR4

It's always Harddisk3 or Harddisk4. Well, I read that those numbers correspond to the disk numbering in the Windows Disk Management. Weird thing is, I've neither a Harddisk3 nor a Harddisk4.

In Disk Management, Disk 0 is a 500 GB HDD, Disk 1 is a 256 GB SSD (on which Windows is installed) and Disk 2 is a 150 GB HDD.
There's no Disk 3 or Disk 4.

What does this mean? I've the idea that the problem started since I moved My Documents to an network drive on my storage server. Could that be the source of the problem? I doubt it, since network drives aren't physical disks.